# cannot export (currently unable) in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

What I want to do is:

```
export * as counterActions from './counter';
```

and the error says:

> Support for experimental syntax 'exportNameSpaceFrom' isn't currently
>   enabled. Add @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from to the plugins section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

I added the plugin but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import * as counterActions from './counter';
export default counterActions;
```